# Obtener nombre de día y mes de una fecha dada por el usuario en un input date js

Tags: javascript, date

tengo un formulario en donde el usuario ingresa una fecha, a partir de esa fecha lo que quiero es mostrarla de la siguiente manera:

Viernes 7 de Abril de 2017

Y lo estoy realizando de la siguiente manera:

```js
let dias = ["Lunes", "Martes", "Miercoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sabado","Domingo"];
let meses = ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"];

  function diaSemana(){
   var x = document.getElementById("fecha");
   let date = new Date(x.value);

           var fechaNum = date.getDate() + 1;
           var mes_name = date.getMonth();

 
      alert(dias[date.getDay()] + " " + fechaNum + " de " + meses[mes_name] + " de " +         date.getFullYear());
      
      }
```

```html
<input type="date" name="fecha" id="fecha" required onchange="diaSemana();">
```

Mi problema es que el nombre del mes en el día 30 de Abril en este caso me pone 31 de abril, y debería de ponerme 1 de Mayo...

Muchas gracias por la atención y por su ayuda!!!

Answer (score 5):

Si deseas ahorrarte usar arreglos con los nombre de los meses puedes hacer esto:

```js
function diaSemana() {
  var x = document.getElementById("fecha");
  let date = new Date(x.value.replace(/-+/g, '/'));

  let options = {
    weekday: 'long',
    year: 'numeric',
    month: 'long',
    day: 'numeric'
  };
  console.log(date.toLocaleDateString('es-MX', options));

}
```

```html
<input type="date" name="fecha" id="fecha" required onchange="diaSemana();">
```

Más informacion en

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString

---

Tu error se debe al formato de la fecha de tu `input` la obtienes de esta forma `2017-01-01` al convertirla a fecha se parsea algo así `Sat Dec 31 2016 18:00:00 GMT-0600 (Hora estándar central (México))`.

Ahora si remplazo los `-` por `/` se parsea de la manera correcta `Sun Jan 01 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Hora estándar central (México))`

Te dejo un ejemplo con lo que menciono anteriormente:

```js
var x = new Date("2017-01-01");
console.log("Formato parseado: 2017-01-01")
console.log(x);
var x = new Date("2017/01/01");
console.log("Formato parseado: 2017/01/01")
console.log(x);
```

Ahora la única linea que modifique fue esta:

```
let date = new Date(x.value);
```

dejándola de esta manera:

```
let date = new Date(x.value.replace(/-+/g, '/'));
```

Quitando el `+ 1` en `var fechaNum = date.getDate();`

y agregando en `dias[date.getDay()]` un `-1` quedando de esta forma `dias[date.getDay()-1]`

```js
let dias = ["Lunes", "Martes", "Miercoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sabado", "Domingo"];
let meses = ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"];

function diaSemana() {
  var x = document.getElementById("fecha");
  let date = new Date(x.value.replace(/-+/g, '/'));

  var fechaNum = date.getDate();
  var mes_name = date.getMonth();


  console.log(dias[date.getDay()-1] + " " + fechaNum + " de " + meses[mes_name] + " de " + date.getFullYear());

}
```

```html
<input type="date" name="fecha" id="fecha" required onchange="diaSemana();">
```

Comment: Dice que es martes... debe ser lunes...  Martes 1 de Mayo de 2017

Comment: @CristinaCarrascoAngulo Corregido gracias por notarlo :D

Comment: Muy bien, :-) Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Una pequeña modificación para que tome el número directo del text:

```js
let dias = ["Lunes", "Martes", "Miercoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sabado","Domingo"];
let meses = ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"];

function diaSemana(){
  var x = document.getElementById("fecha");
  //console.log(x.value);
  //Ya no se obtiene del new Date
  let date = new Date(x.value);
  //var fechaNum = date.getDate() + 1;
  //var mes_name = date.getMonth();
  //console.log(date);
  // console.log(date.getDate());
  
  //Obtengo directo del string y no de la variable tipo fecha
  var fechaString = x.value;
  var mes_name = parseInt( fechaString.substring(5,7))-1;
  console.log(mes_name);
  var fechaNum = fechaString.substring(8,10);
  console.log(fechaNum);
  var year = fechaString.substring(0,4);
  console.log(year);

  alert(dias[date.getDay()] + " " + fechaNum + " de " + meses[mes_name] + " de " +         year);

}
```

```html
<input type="date" name="fecha" id="fecha" required onchange="diaSemana();">
```

Comment: Cristina , recomendaría eliminar las re-declaraciones de `fechaNum` y `mes_name` para evitar confusión con lo que se está haciendo en su código.

Comment: Gracias Joel, añdí los comentarios pertimentes, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Obtener la fecha en hora local  ,teniendo en cuenta la zona horaria del Sistema operativo, sería acceder a `getUTCDate()`

```js
let dias = ["Lunes", "Martes", "Miercoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sabado","Domingo"];
let meses = ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"];
function diaSemana(){
  let date  = new Date(document.getElementById("fecha").value);
  let fechaNum = date.getUTCDate();
  let mes_name = date.getMonth();
 alert(dias[date.getDay()] + " " + fechaNum + " de " + meses[mes_name] + " de " +         date.getFullYear());
}
```

```html
<input type="date" name="fecha" id="fecha" required onchange="diaSemana();">
```

Answer (score 1):

bueno, yo uso una libreria llamada [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/), super facil de usar, y todo lo que hiciste se puede resolver en una sola linea.

```
alert(moment($('#dtpFecha').val()).format('dddd DD [de] MMMM [de] YYYY'));
```

Hize un fiddle con la [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xm2nunb8/).

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta de @JuankGlezz tiene todo lo que necesitas saber. Lo que te pondré aquí es solamente otra alternativa, por si no quieres lidiar todo el tiempo con formatos, cálculos, etc., para fechas. La librería [moment.js](https://momentjs.com) contiene muchos métodos y utilidades que puedes usar para obtener resultados rápidos y confiables. Por ejemplo, tu caso se soluciona con moment de la siguiente manera:

```js
/* establecemos el lenguaje del visitante,
 * por lo tanto, la fecha se mostrará diferente
 * para cada lenguaje.
 */
moment.locale(navigator.language);
/* Offset del time zone del usuario */
const offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();

const fmtDate = strdate => {
  const date = moment(strdate, 'DD/MM/YYYY');
  return date.utcOffset(offset).format('dddd, LL');
};
    
document
  .getElementById('fmt')
  .addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const date = 
      document
        .getElementById('date')
        .value;
    console.info(fmtDate(date));
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.14.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<form id="fmt">
  <input 
    id="date" 
    type="text" 
    value="07/04/2017"
    pattern="^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$"
    title="Ingrese una fecha en formato dd/mm/yyyy"
    required />
  <button type="submit">Format</button>
</form>
```

Comment: En cualquier fecha siempre me manda `Info: Invalid Date`

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tienes corridos los meses.
probaste con:

```js
 var mes_name = date.getMonth()+1;
```

```js
let dias = ["Lunes", "Martes", "Miercoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sabado","Domingo"];
let meses = ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"];

  function diaSemana(){
   var x = document.getElementById("fecha");
   let date = new Date(x.value);

           var fechaNum = date.getDate() + 1;
           var mes_name = date.getMonth();

 
      alert(dias[date.getDay()] + " " + fechaNum + " de " + meses[mes_name] + " de " +         date.getFullYear());
      
      }
```

```html
<input type="date" name="fecha" id="fecha" required onchange="diaSemana();">
```