# Obtener nombre del día de la semana JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, ajax

Estoy intentando obtener el nombre del día de la semana en JavaScript a través de una variable obtenida en PHP. Obtengo bien la fecha en números, es decir, en otro JavaScript que tengo un calendario, pulso sobre un día y me habre otro JavaScript el cual me indica la fecha en número, por ejemplo 16/06/2018. Lo que vengo a preguntar es si también podría obtener el nombre del día de la semana, Lunes, Martes... Sé que hay otro post en este foro sobre algo así pero sólo le indican para obtener el nombre del día de la semana actual, con el GetDate() , pero no encuentro la manera de hacerlo como quiero.

```html
<script src="js/semanal.js"></script>
<?php
if (strpos(getcwd(), 'apen_files') !== false) {
 define('_PS_ADMIN_DIR_', getcwd());
} else {
 define('_PS_ADMIN_DIR_', getcwd().'/includes/apen_files/');
}
 require (_PS_ADMIN_DIR_."/config.php"); 
 
 //-----------------------------------------------------
 $any = $_POST['id_anio']; 

$mes = $_POST['id_mes'];

$dia = $_POST['id_day'];

 ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/estilo.css"/>
<div id="principal_pordias">
 <!-- CONTENEDOR TRABAJO -->
    <!-- ------------------ -->
</div>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<div><center>
<?php echo $any; ?>
</center></div>
<div><center>
<?php echo $mes; ?>
</center></div>
<div><center>
<?php echo $dia; ?>
</center></div>

<script>
var dia = '<?php echo $dia;?>'
var meses = new Array ("Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre");
var diasSemana = new Array("Domingo","Lunes","Martes","Miércoles","Jueves","Viernes","Sábado");
var f=new Date();
document.write(diasSemana['<?php echo $dia;?>']);
</script>
    <div id="fecha"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Así es como lo estaba intentando hacer, pero no me funciona bien, no lo estoy haciendo bien. Aquí os dejo la llamada con AJAX en el javascript semanal.js:

```
function select_pordias(dia, anio, mes) { 
         $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'includes/apen_files/recarga_agenda_pordias.php',
                data: {
                    id_anio:anio,
                    id_mes:mes,
                    id_day:dia
                    },
                success: function (response) {
                    //alert (response);
                    $('#body_center').html(response);
                    }
          });
}
```

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Comment: ¿Qué tiene que ver el ajax (o el css o el html o incluso el php) con el cálculo del día de la semana en Javascript?

Comment: En mi post estoy utilizando html, php, ajax...si te fijas puedes verlo, lo anuncio porque obtengo el dia a través de ajax y estoy utilizando php también. Gracias por tu comentario

Comment: Te podría servir: [Obtener nombre de día y mes de una fecha dada por el usuario en un input date js](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/61400/obtener-nombre-de-día-y-mes-de-una-fecha-dada-por-el-usuario-en-un-input-date-js)